# Code works for one case but not other cases

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object, case

I declared 4 arrays of objects via;

```
Student[,] s2 =new BSIT[10,4];
s2[studCount,iden] = new BSIT();        

Student[,] s3 = new BSCS[10,4];
s3[studCount,iden] = new BSCS();

Student[,] s4 = new MSIT[10,4];
s4[studCount,iden] = new MSIT();

Student[,] s5 = new MSCS[10,4];
s5[studCount,iden] = new MSCS();
```

And then I made some case switch statements that ask for names like:

```
case 1://BSIT
{
     iden=0;
     Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
     (s2[studCount,iden]).setName(Console.ReadLine());
     do
     {
        Console.Write("Enter Age(15-30 only): ");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if(a>=15 && a<=30)
        {
            (s2[studCount,iden]).setAge(a);
            valid=1;
        }
        else
        {
            valid=0;
            Console.WriteLine("INVALID INPUT. TRY AGAIN.");
        }
     }
     while(valid==0);
}
```

But when I tried inputting just the name on other other objects like:

```
case 2://BSCS
{
    iden = 1;
    Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
    (s3[studCount,iden]).setName(Console.ReadLine());       
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Age(15-30 only): ");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if(a>=15 && a<=30)
        {
            (s3[studCount,iden]).setAge(a);
            valid=1;
        }
        else
        {
            valid=0;
            Console.WriteLine("INVALID INPUT. TRY AGAIN.");
        }
    }
    while(valid==0);
}
```

> It gives me the System.NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set to instance of object.

Yes the base class (called "Student") is has all the "Name" setter and getter, while the derived classes BSIT and BSCS both just get the "Name" field from class Student.

**How come the program works fine when I input info for BSIT, but not for BSCS, MSIT, and MSCS? MSIT and MSCS follow the exact same format as BSIT and BSCS, but they still don't work.**

Comment: Oh and just to clarify, BSCS doesn't work too even if it follows the same format as BSIT's case.

Comment: try to set `iden = 0` in **BSCS** and check still it throws exception?

Comment: I can't do that. I need iden = 1 in BSCS because iden = 0 is for BSIT. iden = 1 is for BSCS, iden = 2 is for MSIT, and iden=3 is for MSCS. It works if I set it to zero, but I would be overriding some data later on.

Comment: No you'll not override it, you have different arrays for every discipline. Actually your approach is wrong because you're supposing to put data in one array(thats why you created 4 columns in it) but you also initialized separate arrays for all disciplines. If you have different iden numbers for every discipline, remove all arrays and just keep one array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

You're only initializing 1 element

```
s2[studCount,iden] = new BSIT();
//and so on
```

Which is `0` I suppose, so whenever you access the element on index `[studCount,0]` it works fine. But not other elements.

**Solution:**

```
iden = 1;
Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
s3[studCount,iden] = new BSCS(); //just initialize it before use
(s3[studCount,iden]).setName(Console.ReadLine());
```

**Your Scenario:**

You have to save `Student`s according to their `Discipline`. Thats why you generated an array with 4 columns (BSIT, BSCS, MSIT, MSCS) but you're not using them like you should. You created 4 arrays with 4 columns, now with your approach, your arrays will have empty elements some where in the end.

**Your approach should be:**

You class structure is:

```
Student
    BSIT
    BSCS
    MSIT
    MSCS
```

So just create an array of `Student` and put different child class instances in it.

```
Student[,] students = new Student[10,4]; //index 0 is for BSIT, 1 for BSCS and so on..
```

I am just coding for 2 cases here to help you understand the working:

```
case 1://BSIT
{
     iden = 0;
     Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
     //here you'll initialize the object
     students[studCount, iden] = new BSIT();    //Student is base, so it can contain all of it's child objects

     (students[studCount, iden]).setName(Console.ReadLine());
     do
     {
        Console.Write("Enter Age(15-30 only): ");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if(a>=15 && a<=30)
        {
            (students[studCount, iden]).setAge(a);
            valid=1;
        }
        else
        {
            valid=0;
            Console.WriteLine("INVALID INPUT. TRY AGAIN.");
        }
     }
     while(valid==0);
}

case 2://BSCS
{
    iden = 1;
    Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
    (s3[studCount,iden]).setName(Console.ReadLine());  

    iden = 1;
     Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
     //here you'll initialize the object
     students[studCount, iden] = new BSCS();    //Student is base, so it can contain all of it's child objects (here we're initializing BSCS)

    (students[studCount, iden]).setName(Console.ReadLine()); 
    //your code...
```

Now nothing will override, and all disciplines will be at their specified columns.

Note: I have changed array's name, so please fix it in your code everywhere

Comment: Do I need to initialize it per field? Name isn't the only thing I'm supposed to put in per case. I need to put in things like Age, Gender, and Address.

Comment: @Jester You have an array that _can_ contain objects, but haven't actually put any objects in there.  You need to create the object, then you can set all of the properties on that object as you need.

Comment: No, all fields are in the class, you'll initialize the class just one time. Not need to do it for every field.

Comment: Okay that solved the problem. I do have another problem though, but I'll just make a different question for it. Thank you guys. :)

Comment: @Jester Wait for few minutes, I am updating the answer to help you do it with better approach. You're misunderstanding the OOP here.

Comment: Thank you so much. It now works, but I've encountered a problem that needs a separate question for it. Again, thank you. This has been puzzling me for 4 hours and you just solved it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because in your initialization code you initialize object at indexes `studCount` and `iden`:

```
Student[,] s2 =new BSIT[10,4];
s2[studCount,iden] = new BSIT();
```

So this works fine for case 1, because element at location `studCount,iden` is initialized.

However, for case 2 you are performing this code:

```
iden = 1;
```

So instead of accessing `s2[studCount,0]`, which is initialized, you are accessing `s2[studCount,1]`, which is not initialized (i.e. `s2[studCount,1] == null`)

One way to fix it is before accessing any element of an array, you can verify if it is not null and only then use it:

```
iden = 1;
Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
if(s3[studCount,iden] == null)
    s3[studCount,iden] = new BSCS();
(s3[studCount,iden]).setName(Console.ReadLine());
```

Or initialize all array items immediately after you create an array.

Comment: How exactly do I initialize the other objects then? I wasn't taught how to do that in class.

Comment: You can do a check for null and initialize it if it is null, like I showed in last code snippet of my answer

Comment: Oh I get it. You made an if statement that initializes only if it throws a null value. That's genius.